# A question on an extension of a holomorphic map

Tags: complex-geometry

I encountered the following statement.

Let $X_1$ (resp. $X_2$) be a complex manifold, $D_1$ (resp. $D_2$) a divisor, and 
$f:X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ a holomorphic mapping satisfying

1) $f$ is proper and surjective,

2) $f: X_1 \backslash D_1 \rightarrow X_2 \backslash D_2$ is an isomorphism,

3) $f^{-1}(D_2)=D_1$.

Then any holomorphic mapping $i:D^\times\rightarrow X_2$ from the punctured unit disk $D^\times:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid 0<|z|<1 \}$ to $X_2$ such that $i^{-1}(D_2)=\{0\}$ can be lifted to $\tilde{i}: D^\times \rightarrow X_1$.

I don't know the proof nor a suitable generalization. Can you show it to me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $i^{-1}(D_2)=\{0\} $? $0$ is not in $D^{\times }$.

Comment: Very sorry. I was confused. The right statement is any holomorphic mapping $i: D \rightarrow X_2$ from $D:=\{z\in \mathbb{C} \mid |z|<1\}$ to $X_2$ such that $i^{-1}(D_2)=\{0\}$ can be lifted to $\tilde{i}:D\rightarrow X_1$.